# WIX classic ASP website for IIS 8

Tags: iis, asp-classic, wix, iis-8, wix3.7

I wrote the following WIX settings for a classic ASP website for IIS 7:

```
  <iis:WebSite Id='DefaultWebSite' Description='Default Web Site'>
    <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
  </iis:WebSite>

    <Component Id="MyWebSite_IIS7" Guid="xxx" Transitive="yes" >
        <Condition><![CDATA[IIS_VERSION >= "IIS 7.0" ]]></Condition>
        <CreateFolder/>
        <util:User Id="AnonymousUser7" CreateUser="no" Domain="[DOMAIN_NAME]" Name="[USERNAME]" Password="[PASSWORD]" UpdateIfExists="yes" LogonAsService="yes" />
        <iis:WebAppPool Id="MyWebSitePool" Identity="other" Name="MyAppPool" ManagedPipelineMode="classic" User="AnonymousUser7" />
        <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="MyWebSite_VirtualDir7" Alias="MyWebSite" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION" WebSite="DefaultWebSite"    >
            <iis:WebApplication Id="TestWebApplication7" Name="MyWebSite" WebAppPool="MyWebSitePool" />
            <iis:WebDirProperties Id="MyWebSite_DirProperties7" Read="yes" LogVisits="yes" Index="yes" Script="yes" AnonymousAccess="yes" AnonymousUser="AnonymousUser7"    />
        </iis:WebVirtualDir>
    </Component>
```

Now using IIS 8, I get HTTP 500 error.
How can I avoid this error using WIX?
Currently I am using Wix 3.7 and no plan to upgrade it to the latest Wix doe to the maintenance issue in our company.



Here is another question.
Someone said if I do the following manual steps, it would work:
1. Go to the website you want to add your application to, then double click on Handler Mappings.
2. Click "Add Script Map" and enter in the following information:

- RequestPath: *.asp
- Executable:   C:\Windows\syswow64\inetsrv\asp.dll
- Name: anything


I googled "Add Script Map" and found "appcmd.exe" can add script map, so I tried

```
C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:handlers /+[name='anything',path='*.asp',verb='*',scriptProcessor='%windir%\syswow64\inetsrv\asp.dll',preCondition='MyWebSite']
```

Unfortunately this adds script map for all Default Web Site, not for "MyWebSite". Therefore, as a reault, it didn't resolve HTTP 500 error.
Is there any way to add Script Map using any kind of command / app?

Comment: Do you know what Classic ASP is?  Do you know what ASP.NET is?  Then which are you using?

Comment: @Paul I don't think the OP knows themselves...

Comment: It looks you are smart enough which one I was refering if you look at the code. Do not try to humiliate the people. If you don't know the answer, just leave me alone. People who ask this kind of questions are desperate. They don't ask  to get the negative point.

Comment: Try to get a detailed error message than the 500. Maybe there is something else , other than the handler mapping, wrong ?

Comment: And try this for the appcmd command :  `C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config 'MyWebSite' /section:handlers /+[name='anything',path='*.asp',verb='*',scriptProcessor='%windir%\syswow64\inetsrv\asp.dll']`  from: http://blogs.iis.net/eokim/archive/2010/06/02/understanding-appcmd-exe-list-set-config-configurationpath-section-name-parameter-name-value.aspx

Comment: @LDMS Thank you for changing it to "Classic ASP"

Comment: @SearchAndResQ, When I followed those manual steps, it worked. For your "appcmd", unfortunately I am at home. I will definitely try it when I go back to office. Thank you.

Comment: Nope, didn't work, but HTTP Error 404.3 this time. I see the exactly same behavior with some post [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1630590.aspx?Handler+mapping+adding+with+appcmd+exe+command). Unfortunately I couldn't even look/edit applicationHost.config.

Comment: Okay. I was thinking that specifying the website-name explicitly will make it work..